# How to make multi indexed column headers span multiple columns when they are identical?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have the following code in pandas:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[1,2,3], 'C':[1,2,3], 'D':[1,2,3]})
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, ['span_over']])
```

What I get is this:

```
          A         B         C         D
  span_over span_over span_over span_over
0         1         1         1         1
1         2         2         2         2
2         3         3         3         3
```

What I want is this:

```
                span_over
          A         B         C         D
0         1         1         1         1
1         2         2         2         2
2         3         3         3         3
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Bonus: is it then possible to only do the span over over A and B, and have Span_over2 over C and D, in case there are additional columns?

```
         span_over1     span_over_2
          A         B         C         D
0         1         1         1         1
1         2         2         2         2
2         3         3         3         3
```

Comment: either change the mapping in product: `df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['span_over'],df.columns])` or add `df = df.swaplevel(axis=1)` in the end

Comment: looks like this is spot on. Any way I can select it to only go over certain columns?

Comment: You can reorder index using `df = df.reorder_levels([1,0],axis=1)`

Comment: For the bonus , `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays` , IIUC